# Is this some bug in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a `#container` with 600px width. Inside the `#container` I have 6 `div`s each 200px wide. At a time only 3 `div`s are made to be visible rest can be viewed by scrolling(clicking the side button provided). I have only provided the scrolling functionality for right button since I just need to talk about the issue.

I'm scrolling the container using for loop wherein I increment the value of `conainer.scrollLeft` by one unit in each loop cycle. I know I could have done it by increment operator but I didn't do so in order to highlight the issue. Index value can be changed as per the requirement.

I click the right button and the code runs and values start logging in the console. Those values are of concern. In every loop an integer value is being assigned to the `container.scrollLeft` but actually float values are being logged and that too incorrect. How come is it possible.

On Mozilla Firefox there is no such issue. But on Chrome this problem is occuring. Is it some kind of bug in Chrome and how can we report it.

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Paras_Mahajan/orhcnv8u/6/)

**Update**: I discovered that in Chrome browser one cannot set an integer value to `scrollLeft` except a multiple of 4 when device pixel ratio (DPR) is set to 1.25 and similarly one cannot set it to an integer value except a multiple of 16 if DPR is set to 1.5625 and so on. The pattern is that the very first natural number when multiplied by DPR if gives natural number then former natural number and it's multiples  are the only integer values that `scrollLeft` can be set to.

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
let button_right = document.querySelector('#button_right');

let index;

button_right.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (container.scrollLeft >= 0) {
    for (index = 0; index < 296; index++) {
      container.scrollLeft = index;
      console.log(container.scrollLeft);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  /* border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub {
  height: 75px;
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
}

#button_right {
  margin-left: 8px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 40px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#button_right:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sub1" class="sub"></div>
    <div id="sub2" class="sub"></div>
    <div id="sub3" class="sub"></div>
    <div id="sub4" class="sub"></div>
    <div id="sub5" class="sub"></div>
    <div id="sub6" class="sub"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="button_right">></button>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see any floats when I run the code here or at jsfiddle.

Comment: @freedomn-m I see floats irrespective of the fact I zoom or not

Comment: Ohh I see. If I set scale in my laptops windows setting to 100% all is fine but if I change the scale floats appear. So I think it all depends upon the scaling set via windows setting and not the zooming done in the browser. Did I get it right?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you very much for making it clear. Lastly how is pinch zoom different from the ctr+mouse wheel since pich zoom doesn't has any effect on scrollLeft.

Comment: @freedomn-m Anyways this is a shortcoming of Chrome since one cannot set the value of scrollLeft to be any integer other than a multiple of 4 when device pixel ratio (DPR) is 1.25. Similarly one cannot assign an integer value to scrollLeft other than a multiple of 16 if DPR is 1.5625. And so on. I won't hesitate to call it a ''bug in the Chrome browser".

Comment: @freedomn-m  Ok then can you please help me out to know how I may scroll exactly let say 250px or any other value, but exactly, in Chrome browser independent of what the DPR is set at. I genuinely can't help myselft on this given it's such feature of accepting integer values selectively. I don't want to prove any bugs in the browser. I am just unable achieve scroll under such feature of chrome. Your help will be higly appreciated.